# Security of using predefined shares in Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing

This is related to [Is it possible to create a mix of predefined and generated shares for Shamir's Secret Sharing?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109818/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mix-of-predefined-and-generated-shares-for-shamirs-s), but I have unfortunately lost access to that question and can't merge accounts right now.

I now know that it is most definitely possible to create some predefined shares but was looking for further information on the security of doings this based of a few points.

- Always choose $j$ "arbitrary" shares such that there are always less than $k$ (e.g. $j=1$ in a 3 out of 5 scheme), applies to all below.
- If I randomly generate a short sequence of words (e.g. bip39) and then hash that to a length greater the secret rather than letting a user choose their own "arbitrary" shares.
- A proposed process for something like this would be:

  1. Define Points ($x$,$y$)

     - ($0$, secret)
     - (random $x$, hashed "arbitrary share")
     - (random $x$, random $y$) - $k - 2$ times
  2. Lagrange Interpolation returning polynomial $p$
  3. Generate further shares from $p$

  - "arbitrary share" hashed to length of secret.
  - All Random generators are CSPRNGs.

Comment: The question is there. What do you mean "lost access"? If you can see this  question you can see that question. And the answers are quite detailed.

Comment: I could not comment or accept an answer as it was on a different account and this account did not have enough rep. The answers were great but I just wanted some further clarification, of which I could not comment. But this is off-topic...